# Some users report ClassNotFoundException for launch activity

Tags: android, apk, noclassdeffounderror, google-play

Some users are reporting a crash for my App which I cannot reproduce or even verify.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
    ComponentInfo{my.app/com.example.activity.SplashScreenActivity}: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
    "com.example.activity.SplashScreenActivity" on path: /mnt/asec/my.app-1/pkg.apk
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.activity.SplashScreenActivity" on path: /mnt/asec/my.app-1/pkg.apk
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
  ... 11 more
```

My problem is I get some negative reviews from people who seem unable starting the App at all. I downloaded it on all my test devices from the Play Store and it ran fine.

The systems reported to me where Android 4.1 (Huawei Phone), Android 4.3 (Galaxy S3) and Android 4.4 (Galaxy Note 2).

I disassembled my apk and checked that the class is in fact contained, and referenced properly. And as previously mentioned, none of the devices available to me can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are the `com.example.activity` parts correct? I assume that your package name does not start with `com.example`, right?

Comment: It does not, but these parts are correct. I changed the message accordingly so the names remain correct within context.

Comment: Try to remove some static class references in your Activity and if you use eclipse then remove the checkmark in project properties > build path > order and export > of your Android x.x.x version. I had a similar problem and after that my app runs

Comment: @Happo: since I cannot reproduce the error myself, I wouldn't know which would be "some static class references". Do you mean referencing static class members? Or referencing classes that are marked as static? Also, using Android Studio for build and export.

Comment: I use in my project a provider which need a unique authority which looks like a package path. So thougth i make a String member to keep the authority generic like 'private static final String authority = MyProvider.class.getName()' and exactly this line broke the launch of my app. The funny thing was, that only one user got this error and on all my devices was no problem. I think the way of loading classes is different on some devices

Comment: @Happo: The only references to this I can find in the class are `new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)` and I wouldn't know how to replace those.

Comment: @Lambda Dusk: no this is ok. Then i have no solution for you. Sorry

Comment: @LambdaDusk Did you root cause the problem? I am having the same problem. My app crashes (ClassNotFoundException) for some users who are using Android 4.4.

Comment: @FCA nope, sorry, never did. Am not working there any more, so I can't tell you anything about it now.